# using a while loop instead of for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
secret_word = "python"
correct_word = "yo"
count = 0

for i in secret_word:
 if i in correct_word:
      print(i,end=" ")
 else:
      print('_',end=" ")
```

so the outcome of the code will look like this `_ y _ _ o _`
my question is how i can i get the same output by using while loop instead of using For loop. i know i have to use index to iterate over each character but when i tried i failed . so any help?

```
while count < len(secret_word):
     if correct_word [count]in secret_word[count]:
          print(correct_word,end=" ")
     else:
          print("_",end=" ")
 count = count + 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Let's see the code where you tried and failed.

Comment: You `count` not indented properly. You don't need `count` in `secret_word` just use: `if correct_word[count] in secret_word:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
secret_word = "python"
correct_word = "yo"
count = 0

while count < len(secret_word):
    print(secret_word[count] if secret_word[count] in correct_word else '_', end=" ")
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use `while` is to simulate a pop of the first character. The while loop terminates when the 'truthiness' of a string becomes false with no more characters to process:

```
secret_word = "python"
correct_word = "yo"

while secret_word:
    ch=secret_word[0]
    secret_word=secret_word[1:]
    if ch in correct_word:
        print(ch,end=" ")
    else:
        print('_',end=" ")
```

Or, you can actually use a list with a LH pop:

```
secret_list=list(secret_word)
while secret_list:
    ch=secret_list.pop(0)
    if ch in correct_word:
        print(ch,end=" ")
    else:
        print('_',end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple, way of writing your program with a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop. The code breaks out of an infinite loop when appropriate.

```
def main():
    secret_word = 'python'
    correct_word = 'yo'
    iterator = iter(secret_word)
    sentinel = object()
    while True:
        item = next(iterator, sentinel)
        if item is sentinel:
            break
        print(item if item in correct_word else '_', end=' ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It uses logic similar to how the `for` loop is implemented internally. Alternatively, the example could have used exception handling instead.